# Как посчитать количество символов в каждом элементе списка?

Tags: python, строки, list, список

Дан произвольный текст без чисел, только слова. Текст форматируется и заносится в список, где один элемент - одно слово.

```
def from_file_to_list():
    text = open('text.txt').read().lower().replace('\n','')
    for punctuation_marks in ['.', ',', '!', '?', ':', ';', '–', '…', '»', '«']:
        text = text.replace(punctuation_marks, '')
    list_word = text.split(' ')
    return list_word
```

Надо посчитать количество символов в каждом слове.

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from string import punctuation as punct

def tokenize(
        text: str,
        lower_case: bool = True,
        remove_punctuation: bool = True
) -> list:
    res = text.replace("\n", " ").replace("\r", " ")
    if lower_case:
        res = res.casefold()
    if remove_punctuation:
        res = res.translate(str.maketrans("", "", punct))
    return res.split()

with open(filename) as file:
    tokens = tokenize(file.read())

lengths = dict(zip(tokens, map(len, tokens)))
```

Пример результата:

```
In [159]: lengths = dict(zip(tokens, map(len, tokens)))

In [160]: lengths
Out[160]:
{'дан': 3,
 'произвольный': 12,
 'текст': 5,
 'без': 3,
 'чисел': 5,
 'только': 6,
 'слова': 5,
 'форматируется': 13,
 'и': 1,
 'заносится': 9,
 'в': 1,
 'список': 6,
 'где': 3,
 'один': 4,
 'элемент': 7,
 'одно': 4,
 'слово': 5}
```

или так если нужно оставить дубликаты слов:

```
In [163]: lengths = [[token, len(token)] for token in tokens]

In [164]: lengths
Out[164]:
[['дан', 3],
 ['произвольный', 12],
 ['текст', 5],
 ['без', 3],
 ['чисел', 5],
 ['только', 6],
 ['слова', 5],
 ['текст', 5],
 ['форматируется', 13],
 ['и', 1],
 ['заносится', 9],
 ['в', 1],
 ['список', 6],
 ['где', 3],
 ['один', 4],
 ['элемент', 7],
 ['одно', 4],
 ['слово', 5]]
```

Comment: Мне бы хотелось подыскать вариант попроще, как новичку, без импортирования. Хочу сделать цикл, который будет перебирать всех слова из списка и подсчитывать элементы слов. 
Спасибо!

Comment: @Apetry, я бы посоветовал вам как новичку сразу учиться на идиоматичных примерах, чтобы потом не переучиваться) PS по поводу импорта - можно заменить  импорт переменной: punct = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'

Comment: Гут, спасибо! С вашим кодом удалось разобраться, реально очень помогли)